# Efficient Histogram of Differences for sparse Data

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, sparse-matrix

I want to compute a histogram of the differences between all the elements in one array A with all the elements in another array B.

So I want to have a histogram of the following data:

```
Delta1 = A1-B1
Delta2 = A1-B2
Delta3 = A1-B3
...
DeltaN = A2-B1
DeltaN+1 = A2-B2
DeltaN+2 = A2-B3 
...
```

The point of this calculation is to show that these data has a correlation, even though not every data point has a "partner" in the other array and the correlation is rather noisy in practice.

The problem is that these files are in practice very large, several GB and all entries of the vectors are 64 bit integer numbers with very large differences. 
It seems unfeasible to me to convert these data to binary arrays in order to be able to use correlation functions and fourier transforms to compute this.

Here is a small example to give a better taste of what I'm looking at. 
This implementation with numpy's searchsorted in a for loop is rather slow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timetagsA = [668656283,974986989,1294941174,1364697327,\
1478796061,1525549542,1715828978,2080480431,2175456303,2921498771,3671218524,\
4186901001,4444689281,5087334517,5467644990,5836391057,6249837363,6368090967,8344821453,\
8933832044,9731229532]


timetagsB = [13455,1294941188,1715828990,2921498781,5087334530,5087334733,6368090978,9731229545,9731229800,9731249954]

max_delta_t = 500
nbins = 10000 
histo=np.zeros((nbins,2), dtype = float) 
histo[:,0]=np.arange(0,nbins)   

for i in range(0,int(len(timetagsA))):
    delta_t = 0
    j = np.searchsorted(timetagsB,timetagsA[i]) 
    while (np.round(delta_t) < max_delta_t and j<len(timetagsB)):
        delta_t = timetagsB[j] - timetagsA[i] 

        if(delta_t<max_delta_t):
            histo[int(delta_t),1]+=1 

        j = j+1

plt.plot(histo[0:50,1])
plt.show()
```

It would be great if someone could help me to find a faster way to compute this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The below solution is supposing that your data is so huge that you can not use `np.substract` with `np.outer` and then slice the value you want to keep:

```
arr_diff = np.subtract.outer(arrB, arrA)
print (arr_diff[(0<arr_diff ) &(arr_diff <max_delta_t)])
# array([ 14,  12,  10,  13, 216,  11,  13, 268], dtype=int64)
```

with your example data it works but not with too huge data set

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION**

Let's first suppose your `max_delta_t` is smaller than the difference between two successive values in `timetagsB` for an easy way of doing it (then we can try to generalize it).

```
#create the array instead of list
arrA = np.array(timetagsA)
arrB = np.array(timetagsB)
max_delta_t = np.diff(arrB).min() - 1 #here it's 202 just for the explanation
```

You can use `np.searchsorted` in a vectorize way:

```
# create the array of search 
arr_search = np.searchsorted(arrB, arrA) # the position of each element of arrA in arrB
print (arr_search)
# array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7],dtype=int64)
```

You can calculate the difference between the element of `arrB` corresponding to each element of `arrA` by slicing `arrB` with `arr_search`

```
# calculate the difference
arr_diff = arrB[arr_search] - arrA
print (arr_diff[arr_diff<max_delta_t]) # finc the one smaller than max_delta_t
# array([14, 12, 10, 13, 11, 13], dtype=int64)
```

So what you are looking for is then calculated by [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)

```
arr_bins = np.bincount(arr_diff[arr_diff<max_delta_t])
#to make it look like histo but not especially necessary
histo = np.array([range(len(arr_bins)),arr_bins]).T
```

Now the problem is that, there is some values of difference between `arrA` and `arrB` that could not be obtained with this method, when `max_delta_t` is bigger than two successive values in `arrB`. Here is one way, naybe not the most efficient depending on the values of your data. For any value of `max_delta_t`

```
#need an array with the number of elements in arrB for each element of arrA 
# within a max_delta_t range
arr_diff_search = np.searchsorted(arrB, arrA + max_delta_t)- np.searchsorted(arrB, arrA)
#do a loop to calculate all the values you are interested in
list_arr = []
for i in range(arr_diff_search.max()+1):
    arr_diff = arrB[(arr_search+i)%len(arrB)][(arr_diff_search>=i)] - arrA[(arr_diff_search>=i)]
    list_arr.append(arr_diff[(0<arr_diff)&(arr_diff<max_delta_t)])
```

Now you can `np.concatenate` the list_arr and use `np.bincount` such as:

```
arr_bins = np.bincount(np.concatenate(list_arr))
histo = np.array([range(len(arr_bins)),arr_bins]).T
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I just wanted to try this on a larger file and I got a TypeError: "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'". This happened in the penultimate line (bincount).

Comment: @Mechanix maybe try to add `astype(int)` inside `bincount` to cast the float to int, such as `np.bincount(arr_diff[arr_diff<max_delta_t].astype(int))`

Comment: I just tried the second example that you gave. for that I converted the content of a=np.concatenate(list_arr) to an array of long integers with a=map(long,a). The lets bincount just throw a memory error. Your first example already throws a memory error at "arr_diff = np.subtract.outer(arrB, arrA)".

Comment: If you want to test your program with slightly larger files, maybe can you have a look here? https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0e6k15u6bef9cc/arrB.txt?dl=1, https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2f5063gxdtvddx/arrA.txt?dl=1

Comment: For the long integer, of what I know, they have been [unified](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) with int a while ago, but not sure what it means for your case. It makes sense that the first method throws an error with big data, for the second, not sure why. But if the `list_arr` contains all the data you need and there is not a memory error, then maybe another method than `np.bincount` should be used.

Comment: @Mechanix I tried with your data and I found a mistake in my idea: see `list_arr.append(...` in the loop `for`, but once fixed it runs well on my computer with your bigger data

Comment: Wow, this is ~65 times faster than the method I tried before for this dataset. This is really crazy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have another question: I now have to adopt this solution to a case where the numbers are not integers and where the bin size is smaller than 1. In the slow solution that I posted, it would be just  nbins = int(np.round((max_delta_t/binwidth)))+1.  How can i adjust the bin width in the case of your solution?

Comment: @Mechanix it seems that the input array (here `np.concatenate(list_arr)`) must be integers and that bin size is 1 according to the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). Not sure but a work around could be multiply or divide your data by `binwidth` and keep the `floor` of these numbers and do the above method with bin size of 1. The result may be equivalent, but once again I'm really not sure.